# How to find eigenvalues?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method

I have the following system of differetial equations, which are linearized based on steady state solutions. How to discretize them and find eigenvalues or use any other method without discretization to find eigenvalues.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(*parameters*)
B=0.11;ita = 1.0;F =0.28;
(*steady-state solutions*)
v[z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) z];
a[z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) z];
h[z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) z] Sqrt[((4.0 B)/F) + (1 - ((4.0 B)/F)) Exp[(F/4.0 ita)z]];
(*linearized equations*)
eq1=\[Lambda] a1[z] + a[z] v1'[z] + a'[z] v1[z] + v[z] a1'[z] + v'[z] a1[z] == 0; 
eq2=\[Lambda] a[z] h1[z] - a[z] h[z] v1'[z] - a[z] v'[z] h1[z] - h[z] v'[z] a1[z] + v[z] h[z] a1'[z] + v[z] a'[z] h1[z] + h[z] a'[z] v1[z] + (F/(2.0 *ita)) h1[z] == 0; 
eq3=\[Lambda] (h[z]^2 a1[z] - 2.0 a[z] h[z] h1[z]) - 2.0  a[z] v[z] h[z] h1'[z] - 2.0  a[z] v[z] h'[z] h1[z] - 2.0  a[z] h[z] h'[z] v1[z] - 2.0  v[z] h[z] h'[z] a1[z] + v[z] h[z]^2 a1'[z] + 2.0  v[z] a'[z] h[z] h1[z] + h[z]^2 a'[z] v1[z] - ((2.0 *B)/ita)a[z]a1[z] == 0.0;
(* boundary conditions*)
bc1=a1[0] == 0.0001; bc2=v1[0] == 0.0001; bc3=h1[0] == 0.0001;
```

Here, a[z], v[z], and h[z] are steady-state solutions and a1[z], v1[z] and h1[z] are small perturbations. [Lambda] is the eigenvalues needs to find. The domain for z is [0,10]. Also, here a[0]=h[0]=v[0]=1. Please help. Thanks.

N.B. a few days ago, I made a related post, but I now realize that I need to make some modifications to the equations and boundary conditions.

Comment: I do not understand the question. You have 3 differential equations, with some unknown $\lambda$ in them. How exactly should $\lambda$ be determined? i.e. what is the criteria? At school we only looked at finding eigenvalues for system of ode's of the form `x'=A x` where the eigenvalues are for the `A` matrix. This is when solving system of ode's using the eigenvalue/eigenfunction method. I never seen a setup like you have where you insert directly what you call $\lambda$ into the system and then try to find its value. Based on what? Do you have a link that explains this setup or an example?

Comment: May be what you mean is you want to find value for $\lambda$ which makes the three solutions go back, eventually, to the rest position after being perturbated? Is this what you mean? In this case you have to do this analytically. Because NDSolve will not work with unknown quantity in the ode's. Unless you do simulation trying different values.

Comment: The eigenvalues can be determined by converting the equations to an algebraic eigenvalue problem by replacing the derivatives with finite differencs or other discretization method @Nasser

Comment: You might start by looking at the documentation for NDEigenvalues and related functions at the bottom of the page. If you choose to discretize, there are related linear algebra functions such as NEigenvalues etc. which handle such cases.

Comment: Is it possible for you to have a look on this problem @ bbgodfrey. I have modified it from the previous one.

Comment: Thanks; it will be really a great help.@bbgodfrey

Comment: Your equations do not contain a term of the form `\[Lambda] v1[z]`.  Consequently, `\[Lambda]` can be eliminated from `eq3`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Your system of equations is not an eigenvalue problem, because it contains only initial values.  Nonetheless, the equations can be solved numerically without difficulty.  For `\[Lambda] > 0`, `a1` and `h1` decrease exponentially, while `v1` remains approximately constant.  However, for `\[Lambda] < 0`, `a1` and `h1` increase exponentially, while `v1` again remains approximately constant.  I do not see what additional conclusions can be drawn from the equations as given.

Comment: \[Lambda] comes from the time derivative was not present for v[z]. I will check the equations again, probably I made a mistake somewhere. However, I would like to see only how to get eigenvalues by converting equations to an algebraic eigen value problem by discretizing them. The equations then can be reduced to \[Lambda] U x= Wx. In Matlab they have Chebfun for doing that by using Cebyshev collocation. All I need is to see one example with even another or modified these equations @bbgodfrey

Comment: Mathematica has tools for decomposing functions with wavelets, finite elements, etc.  However, because the system above does not yield unique eigenvalues, it is very unlikely that decomposing it will.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me one example @bbgodfrey. Actually, there will be many eigenvalues based on the number of discretization points and I am in the persuit of eigenvalue with the largest real parts.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish, so I do not know how to help you further.

Comment: No problem dear @bbgodfrey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this problem as an optimization problem using `NMinimize` and the Euler wavelets collocation method as follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(*parameters*)
B = 0.11; ita = 1.0; F = 0.28; L = 10;
(*steady-state solutions*)
v[z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) z];
a[z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) z];
h[z_] := 
  Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) z] Sqrt[((4.0 B)/
       F) + (1 - ((4.0 B)/F)) Exp[(F/4.0 ita) z]];
(*linearized equations*)
eq1 = \[Lambda] a1[z] + a[z] v1'[z] + a'[z] v1[z] + v[z] a1'[z] + 
   v'[z] a1[z];
eq2 = \[Lambda] a[z] h1[z] - a[z] h[z] v1'[z] - a[z] v'[z] h1[z] - 
   h[z] v'[z] a1[z] + v[z] h[z] a1'[z] + v[z] a'[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z] a'[z] v1[z] + (F/(2.0*ita)) h1[z];
eq3 = \[Lambda] (h[z]^2 a1[z] - 2.0 a[z] h[z] h1[z]) - 
   2.0 a[z] v[z] h[z] h1'[z] - 2.0 a[z] v[z] h'[z] h1[z] - 
   2.0 a[z] h[z] h'[z] v1[z] - 2.0 v[z] h[z] h'[z] a1[z] + 
   v[z] h[z]^2 a1'[z] + 2.0 v[z] a'[z] h[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z]^2 a'[z] v1[z] - ((2.0*B)/ita) a[z] a1[z];
(*boundary conditions*)
bc1 = a1[0] == 0.0001; bc2 = v1[0] == 0.0001; bc3 = h1[0] == 0.0001;
(*Here,a[z],v[z],and h[z] are steady-state solutions and a1[z],v1[z] \
and h1[z] are small perturbations.[Lambda] is the eigenvalues needs \
to find.The domain for z is[0,10].Also,here a[0]=h[0]=v[0]=1.*)

UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;


V1 = Array[vv1, {nn}]; A1 = Array[aa1, {nn}]; H1 = Array[hh1, {nn}];
da1[s_] := A1 . Psi[s]/L; a1[s_] := A1 . int1[s] + a0; 
dh1[s_] := H1 . Psi[s]/L; h1[s_] := H1 . int1[s] + h0; 
dv1[s_] := V1 . Psi[s]/L; v1[s_] := V1 . int1[s] + v0;
rule = {a1'[z] -> da1[s], a1[z] -> a1[s], h1'[z] -> dh1[s], 
  h1[z] -> h1[s], v1'[z] -> dv1[s], 
  v1[z] -> v1[s]}; eq = {eq1, eq2, eq3} /. rule /. z -> L s; eqs = 
 Flatten[Table[eq, {s, ycol}]];

var = Join[{\[Lambda] , a0, h0, v0}, A1, H1, V1]; sol = 
 NMinimize[{eqs . eqs, {bc1, bc2, bc3}}, var]
```

Visualization

```
Plot[Evaluate[{a1[z/L], h1[z/L], v1[z/L]} /. sol[[2]]], {z, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"a1", "h1", "v1"}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"\[Lambda]=", \[Lambda] /. sol[[2]]}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Alex Trounev. I really appreciate your help and sorry for my late response.

Comment: Would you mind having a look on my codes @Alex Trounev. I did it by using Cebyshev Collocation method. But could not find the correct command for generalized eigenvalue problem \[lambda]UX=WX,where W is non-singular invertible matrix.

Comment: @Fun123 Unfortunately `W` is badly conditioned matrix  therefore we can't solve this problem using `Inverse[W]` or  `Eigenvalues[{W, U}]`.  Also solution given in my answer is not unique.