# What is mathematica command for finding eigenvalues of a generalized eigenvalue problem?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, linear-algebra

The provided code below is designed to compute the eigenvalues for the problem I inquired about earlier in this post: [How to find eigenvalues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289044/how-to-find-eigenvalues/289145#289145). I believe my code is mostly accurate, with the exception of the final line. Could someone please assist in determining the correct command for solving the generalized eigenvalue problem, [Lambda]UX = WX, where W is a non-singular, invertible matrix? Matlab includes the QZ algorithm for addressing such problems. What is the Mathematica counterpart?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ClearAll[recurrenceTables];
recurrenceTables[x_?VectorQ, n_] := Module[{T, Tprime}, T = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
Tprime = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
T[[1]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
T[[2]] = x;
Tprime[[1]] = ConstantArray[0., Length[x]];
Tprime[[2]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
Do[T[[i]] = 2. x T[[i - 1]] - T[[i - 2]];
Tprime[[i]] = 2. T[[i - 1]] + 2. x Tprime[[i - 1]] - Tprime[[i - 2]];, {i, 3, n + 1}];
{Transpose[T], Transpose[Tprime]}];

n = 5;(* Collocation points*)
B = 0.11; ita = 1.0; F = 0.28; L = 10;(*parameters*)

 (*Definig Collocation points*)
 y = (L/2) + (L/2)*Cos[N[Pi/n] Range[0., n]];
{T, Tprime} = recurrenceTables[y, n];

 (*Defining all the functions we need*)
Z[x_] := (L*(x + 1.0))/2.0;
v[Z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z];
a[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z];
h[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z] Sqrt[((4.0 B)/F) + (1 - ((4.0 B)/F)) Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z]];

Zy = Map[Z, y];
Vbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v, Zy]]];
Vbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v', Zy]]];

Abar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a, Zy]]];
Abarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a', Zy]]];

Hbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h, Zy]]];
Hbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h', Zy]]];

(*creating entries of the final U and W matrix below*)
A1 = 2.0 Vbar . Tprime + Vbarprime . T;
V1 = 2.0 Abar . Tprime + Abarprime . T;
T2 = Abar . T;
V2 = Hbar . Abarprime . T - 2.0 Abar . Hbar . Tprime;
A2 = 2.0 Vbar . Hbar . Tprime - Hbar . Vbarprime . T;
H2 = Vbar . Abarprime . T - Abar . Vbarprime . T + (F/(2.0*ita)) T;
T31 = Hbar . Hbar . T;
T32 = 2.0 Abar . Hbar . T;
F2 = -(1/(2.0 *ita)) T;
H3 = 2.0  Vbar . Abarprime . Hbar . T - 2.0 Abar . Vbar . Hbarprime . T - 4.0 Abar . Vbar . Hbar . Tprime;
V3 = Hbar . Hbar . Abarprime . T - 2.0 Abar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T;
A3 = 2.0 Vbar . Hbar . Hbar . Tprime - 2.0 Vbar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T - (2.0/ita) B Abar . T;

(*final generalized eigenvalue problem \[Lambda]UX=WX *)
U = ArrayFlatten[{{T, 0. T, 0. T}, {0.0, 0.0, T2}, {T31, 0.0, -T32}}];
W = ArrayFlatten[{{-A1, -V1, 0.0}, {-A2, -V2, -H2}, {-A3, -V3, -H3}}];
Vals = Eigenvalues[{W, U}]
```

Comment: Help says **Eigenvalues[{m,a}] gives the generalized eigenvalues of m with respect to a.** I do not know if this applies to what you have.

Comment: Thank you so much but I could not understand how to apply this document of WOLFRAM for generalized eigenvalues @Nasser:https://reference.wolfram.com/applications/insydes/ReferenceManual/GeneralizedEigenvalues.html

Comment: You are looking at some old documentation of some specific package/application it seems. I meant the main documentation [Eigenvalues.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html)  see the second entry at the top.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for the clarification @Nasser

Comment: @Fun123 You solution is valid for `L=1` only. To extend it to `L=10` use  `Z[x_] :=L ((x + 1.0))/2.0`. Unfortunately, matrix `W` is not invertible.  Therefore we can try to solve this problem with `NMInimize` as in my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289044/how-to-find-eigenvalues/289145#289145

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I fixed it for defining collocation points as well. The non-zero determinant of square matrix W does not imply it is invertible? In my problem I was expecting an imaginary parts of eigenvalue as well; I am not sure I will be able to reproduce your codes for my another problem with my limited knowlege in mathematica and the technique you used. Anyway, thank you so much for your help @AlexTrounev

Comment: @Fun123 Please, pay attention that you use `L` in `y` definition and again in `Z` definition. Use `Z[x_]:=x; y = Reverse[(L/2) + (L/2)*Cos[N[Pi/n] Range[0., n]]]; Zy=y';`.  Add `Union` to  `Vals = Union[Eigenvalues[{W, U}]]` to eliminate `Indeterminate, ComplexInfinity`. Then for `n=17` as in my example you will see the real root -0.830102, that is close to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexTrounev. You helped me so much.  I think I undersood why you used Z[x_]:=x; (My mistake! I used linear transformation of the interval [-1,1] twice).  However, I do not understand why you used Reverse?

Comment: Also, Zy=y'; produces error in my run. I have one more question, why I could not see almost same dominant eigenvalue for different n.@AlexTrounev

Comment: @Fun123 `Reverse` used to make order from 0 to 10. Use `Zy=y` instead of your `Zy = Map[Z, y]`.

Comment: Thanks again @AlexTrounev

Comment: @Fun123 There are several typos in your code. So, I did two codes with the same results. One is your code without typos and one new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several typos in the code with matrix `U,W` definition. After cleaning, the code looks like this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ClearAll[recurrenceTables];
recurrenceTables[x_?VectorQ, n_] := 
  Module[{T, Tprime}, T = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
   Tprime = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
   T[[1]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
   T[[2]] = x;
   Tprime[[1]] = ConstantArray[0., Length[x]];
   Tprime[[2]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
   Do[T[[i]] = 2. x T[[i - 1]] - T[[i - 2]];
    Tprime[[i]] = 
     2. T[[i - 1]] + 2. x Tprime[[i - 1]] - Tprime[[i - 2]];, {i, 3, 
     n + 1}];
   {Transpose[T], Transpose[Tprime]}];

n = 9;(*Collocation points*)
B = 0.11; ita = 1.0; F = 0.28; L = 10;(*parameters*)

(*Definig Collocation points*)
y = -Cos[N[Pi/n] Range[0., n]];
{T, Tprime} = recurrenceTables[y, n];
Tprime = 2 Tprime/L;
(*Defining all the functions we need*)
Z[x_] := L (x + 1)/2;
v[Z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z];
a[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z];
h[Z_] := 
  Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z] Sqrt[((4.0 B)/
       F) + (1 - ((4.0 B)/F)) Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z]];

Zy = Map[Z, y];
Vbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v, Zy]]];
Vbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v', Zy]]];

Abar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a, Zy]]];
Abarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a', Zy]]];

Hbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h, Zy]]];
Hbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h', Zy]]];


(*creating entries of the final U and W matrix below, \
solution={a1,h1,v1}*)
eq1 = \[Lambda] a1[z] + a[z] v1'[z] + a'[z] v1[z] + v[z] a1'[z] + 
   v'[z] a1[z];
eq2 = \[Lambda] a[z] h1[z] - a[z] h[z] v1'[z] - a[z] v'[z] h1[z] - 
   h[z] v'[z] a1[z] + v[z] h[z] a1'[z] + v[z] a'[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z] a'[z] v1[z] + (F/(2.0*ita)) h1[z];
eq3 = \[Lambda] (h[z]^2 a1[z] - 2.0 a[z] h[z] h1[z]) - 
   2.0 a[z] v[z] h[z] h1'[z] - 2.0 a[z] v[z] h'[z] h1[z] - 
   2.0 a[z] h[z] h'[z] v1[z] - 2.0 v[z] h[z] h'[z] a1[z] + 
   v[z] h[z]^2 a1'[z] + 2.0 v[z] a'[z] h[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z]^2 a'[z] v1[z] - ((2.0*B)/ita) a[z] a1[z];

T2 = Abar . T; T31 = Hbar . Hbar . T;
T32 = -2.0 Abar . Hbar . 
   T; U = -ArrayFlatten[{{T, 0. T, 0. T}, {0. T, T2, 0. T}, {T31, T32,
      0. T}}];
A1 = Vbar . Tprime + Vbarprime . T; H1 = 0. T;
V1 = Abar . Tprime + Abarprime . T;
V2 = Hbar . Abarprime . T - Abar . Hbar . Tprime;
A2 = Vbar . Hbar . Tprime - Hbar . Vbarprime . T;
H2 = Vbar . Abarprime . T - Abar . Vbarprime . T + (F/(2.0*ita)) T;
H3 = -2. Abar . Vbar . Hbar . Tprime - 
   2. Abar . Vbar . Hbarprime . T + 2. Vbar . Abarprime . Hbar . T;
V3 = Hbar . Hbar . Abarprime . T - 2.0 Abar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T;
A3 = Vbar . Hbar . Hbar . Tprime - 
  2.0 Vbar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T - (2.0 B/ita) Abar . T; W = 
 ArrayFlatten[{{A1, H1, V1}, {A2, H2, V2}, {A3, H3, V3}}];
```

With this code we compute eigenvalues as follows

```
(*final generalized eigenvalue problem \[Lambda]UX=WX*)Vals =
  Union[Eigenvalues[{W, U}]]

(*Out[]= {-2.24273 + 0. I, -1.68633 + 0. I, -1.28402 + 
  0. I, -0.970793 - 0.514233 I, -0.970793 + 0.514233 I, -0.888949 + 
  0. I, -0.665724 + 0. I, -0.449759 + 0. I, -0.269871 - 
  0.459168 I, -0.269871 + 0.459168 I, -0.245564 + 0. I, -0.119623 + 
  0. I, -0.0396647 + 0. I, -0.00916759 + 0. I, -0.00134319 + 0. I, 
 1.94998*10^-7 + 0. I, 0.0615641 - 0.304778 I, 0.0615641 + 0.304778 I,
  0.203549 - 0.105815 I, 0.203549 + 0.105815 I, ComplexInfinity}*)
```

To be sure of the results we get, we have compiled second code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
n = 9;(*Collocation points*)
B = 0.11; ita = 1.0; F = 0.28; L = 10;(*parameters*)

(*Definig Collocation points*)
y = -Cos[N[Pi/n] Range[0., n]];

vec[x_] := Table[ChebyshevT[n, x], {n, 0, 9}]; Map[vec, y];
vec1[x_] := Table[i ChebyshevU[-1 + i, x], {i, 0, 9}]; Map[vec1, y];

(*Defining all the functions we need*)
Z[x_] := L (x + 1)/2;
v[Z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z];
a[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z];
h[Z_] := 
  Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z] Sqrt[((4.0 B)/
       F) + (1 - ((4.0 B)/F)) Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z]];

Zy = Map[Z, y];
V0 = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v, Zy]]];
V0p = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v', Zy]]];

A0 = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a, Zy]]];
A0p = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a', Zy]]];

H0 = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h, Zy]]];
H0p = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h', Zy]]];


AA1 = Array[aa, n + 1]; HH1 = Array[hh, n + 1]; VV1 = 
 Array[vv, n + 1]; a1[y_] := AA1 . vec[y]; h1[y_] := HH1 . vec[y]; 
v1[y_] := VV1 . vec[y]; a1p[y_] := AA1 . vec1[y]; 
h1p[y_] := HH1 . vec1[y]; v1p[y_] := VV1 . vec1[y];
A1 = Map[a1, y]; H1 = Map[h1, y]; V1 = Map[v1, y]; A1p = 
 2/L Map[a1p, y]; H1p = 2/L Map[h1p, y]; V1p = 2/L Map[v1p, y];

eq1 = \[Lambda] a1[z] + a[z] v1'[z] + a'[z] v1[z] + v[z] a1'[z] + 
   v'[z] a1[z];
eq2 = \[Lambda] a[z] h1[z] - a[z] h[z] v1'[z] - a[z] v'[z] h1[z] - 
   h[z] v'[z] a1[z] + v[z] h[z] a1'[z] + v[z] a'[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z] a'[z] v1[z] + (F/(2.0*ita)) h1[z];
eq3 = \[Lambda] (h[z]^2 a1[z] - 2.0 a[z] h[z] h1[z]) - 
   2.0 a[z] v[z] h[z] h1'[z] - 2.0 a[z] v[z] h'[z] h1[z] - 
   2.0 a[z] h[z] h'[z] v1[z] - 2.0 v[z] h[z] h'[z] a1[z] + 
   v[z] h[z]^2 a1'[z] + 2.0 v[z] a'[z] h[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z]^2 a'[z] v1[z] - ((2.0*B)/ita) a[z] a1[z];


eqs = Join[\[Lambda] A1 + A0 . V1p + A0p . V1 + V0 . A1p + 
    V0p . A1, \[Lambda] A0 . H1 - A0 . H0 . V1p - A0 . V0p . H1 - 
    H0 . V0p . A1 + V0 . H0 . A1p + V0 . A0p . H1 + 
    H0 . A0p . 
     V1 + (F/(2.0*ita)) H1 , \[Lambda] (H0 . H0 . A1 - 
       2.0 A0 . H0 . H1 ) - 2.0 A0 . V0 . H0 . H1p - 
    2.0 A0 . V0 . H0p . H1 - 2.0 A0 . H0 . H0p . V1 - 
    2.0 V0 . H0 . H0p . A1 + V0 . H0 . H0 . A1p + 
    2.0 V0 . A0p . H0 . H1 + 
    H0 . H0 . A0p . V1 - ((2.0*B)/ita) A0 . A1 ];

(*creating entries of the final U and W matrix below*)var = 
 Join[AA1, HH1, VV1]; {v, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqs, var]

W = Normal[mat] /. \[Lambda] -> 0; U = 
 W - Normal[mat] /. \[Lambda] -> 1;
```

Solution

```
{val, fun} = Eigensystem[{W, U}];

val // Union

(*Out[]= {-2.24273 + 0. I, -1.68633 + 0. I, -1.28402 + 
  0. I, -0.970793 + 0.514233 I, -0.970793 - 0.514233 I, -0.888949 + 
  0. I, -0.665724 + 0. I, -0.449759 + 0. I, -0.269871 - 
  0.459168 I, -0.269871 + 0.459168 I, -0.245564 + 0. I, -0.119624 + 
  0. I, -0.0396647 + 0. I, -0.00916761 + 0. I, -0.00134317 + 0. I, 
 1.94951*10^-7 + 0. I, 0.0615641 - 0.304778 I, 0.0615641 + 0.304778 I,
  0.203549 - 0.105815 I, 0.203549 + 0.105815 I, ComplexInfinity}*)
```

Comment: Many many thanks @Alex Trounev

Comment: I also am looking for eigenvalue(dominant eigenvalue) which will remain almost unchanged with the increase of collocation point n. How to get that? @Alex Trounev

Comment: @Fun123 In your case it should be something around zero. But you need to formulate criteria, for example,  $Min|\lambda|$, or $Max Re(\lambda), Re(\lambda)<0$ and so on.

Comment: How to code the criteria in Mathematica? I am sorry, I think I did not quite get it.@Alex Trounev

Comment: @Fun123 It depends on what you want to explore. I have code to compute eigenvalue with minimal `Abs` and `Abs[Re[]]` part.

Comment: I want to explore the eigenvalue with the largest real part at the same time it will remain almost unchanged with varying collocation points. It will the determine the nature/stability of steady state solutions.Right now, I see them one by one with different collocation point but could not find the stable one.@Alex Trounev

Comment: Do you mean largest in `Abs[Re[]]`?

Comment: Actually, I want to pick that eigenvalue which remain almost unchanged regardlesss of collocation points. For example, let, eigenvalue=-0.512+0.i is dominant for the collocation point n=50; now, I will check if it is amost the same point for other collocation points, let's say, for n=100 it is almost same as -0.511+0.i. I do not care about other eigenvalues,only need the one is almost repeated. Is there any way to code this in Mathematica? Now, I do it by looking at every eigenvalues for different collocation points which is time consuming and misleading.@Alex Trounev

Comment: I think it could be done by saving the outputs of eigenvalues for any n and then compare one by one whithin specific bounds or tolerance for another n or there could be another way. But I could not produce it with my limited knowledge in Mathematica. @Alex Trounev

Comment: Actually your main question has answer above. It looks like your question about specific eigenvalue  could be better to discuss in a new topic. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I will post it as a new question.Thanks for the suggestion@Alex Trounev

Comment: Dear @Alex Trounev, here I posed the new question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289533/how-to-explore-the-stable-eigenvalue-with-the-largest-real-part

Comment: Dear @Alex Trounev, sorry to ask you an old question which I have not noticed until recently. Please let me understand why you wrote Tprime= 2 Tprime/L on your first codes. I understand that factor 2 is adjusted for other terms later but did not quite get why you divided Tprime by L.

Comment: We use `Z[x_] := L (x + 1)/2;` it is why `D[f, Z]=L/2 D[f,x]` therefore `D[f,x]=2/L D[f,Z]`.

Comment: Yes, in Mathematica symbol `D` is derivative. And we need to compute `D[T[n, x],x]` while we know `T'[n, Z]`. For this we use rule `D[f, x]=D[Z, x] D[f, Z]`.

Comment: Dear @Alex Trounev, could you please have a look on my new question which is based on same topic of this question:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291419/how-to-incorporate-boundary-conditions