# How to explore the unchanged eigenvalue with the largest real part?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, linear-algebra

The provided code below employs the Chebyshev collocation method to calculate eigenvalues. I'm interested in examining the eigenvalue with the largest real part while ensuring it remains almost same as the number of collocation points varies. My idea is to store the eigenvalue outputs for different 'n' values and then compare them within certain predefined bounds or tolerance when 'n' changes. However, I'm struggling to implement this in Mathematica due to my limited expertise. I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ClearAll[recurrenceTables];
recurrenceTables[x_?VectorQ, n_] := Module[{T, Tprime}, T = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
Tprime = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
T[[1]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
T[[2]] = x;
Tprime[[1]] = ConstantArray[0., Length[x]];
Tprime[[2]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
Do[T[[i]] = 2. x T[[i - 1]] - T[[i - 2]];
Tprime[[i]] = 2. T[[i - 1]] + 2. x Tprime[[i - 1]] - Tprime[[i - 2]];, {i, 3, n + 1}];
{Transpose[T], Transpose[Tprime]}];

n = 50;(*Collocation points*)
B = 0.11; ita = 1.0; F = 0.28; L = 10;(*parameters*)

(*Definig Collocation points*)
y = -Cos[N[Pi/n] Range[0., n]];
{T, Tprime} = recurrenceTables[y, n];
Tprime = 2 Tprime/L;
(*Defining all the functions we need*)
Z[x_] := L (x + 1)/2;
v[Z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z];
a[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z];
h[Z_] :=  Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z] Sqrt[((4.0 B)/F) + (1 - ((4.0 B)/F)) Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z]];

Zy = Map[Z, y];
Vbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v, Zy]]];
Vbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v', Zy]]];

Abar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a, Zy]]];
Abarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a', Zy]]];

Hbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h, Zy]]];
Hbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h', Zy]]];

(*creating entries of the final U and W matrix below*)
T2 = Abar . T; T31 = Hbar . Hbar . T;
T32 = -2.0 Abar . Hbar .  T;
U = -ArrayFlatten[{{T, 0. T, 0. T}, {0. T, T2, 0. T}, {T31, T32,0. T}}];
A1 = Vbar . Tprime + Vbarprime . T; H1 = 0. T;
V1 = Abar . Tprime + Abarprime . T;
V2 = Hbar . Abarprime . T - Abar . Hbar . Tprime;
A2 = Vbar . Hbar . Tprime - Hbar . Vbarprime . T;
H2 = Vbar . Abarprime . T - Abar . Vbarprime . T + (F/(2.0*ita)) T;
H3 = -2. Abar . Vbar . Hbar . Tprime - 2. Abar . Vbar . Hbarprime . T + 2. Vbar . Abarprime . Hbar . T;
V3 = Hbar . Hbar . Abarprime . T - 2.0 Abar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T;
A3 = Vbar . Hbar . Hbar . Tprime - 2.0 Vbar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T - (2.0 B/ita) Abar . T; 
W =ArrayFlatten[{{A1, H1, V1}, {A2, H2, V2}, {A3, H3, V3}}];
Vals = Union[Eigenvalues[{W, U}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look up clusters of eigenvalues at different number of collocation points as follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ClearAll[recurrenceTables];
recurrenceTables[x_?VectorQ, n_] := 
  Module[{T, Tprime}, T = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
   Tprime = ConstantArray[0., {n + 1}];
   T[[1]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
   T[[2]] = x;
   Tprime[[1]] = ConstantArray[0., Length[x]];
   Tprime[[2]] = ConstantArray[1., Length[x]];
   Do[T[[i]] = 2. x T[[i - 1]] - T[[i - 2]];
    Tprime[[i]] = 
     2. T[[i - 1]] + 2. x Tprime[[i - 1]] - Tprime[[i - 2]];, {i, 3, 
     n + 1}];
   {Transpose[T], Transpose[Tprime]}];

Do[n = i;(*Collocation points*)
 B = 0.11; ita = 1.0; F = 0.28; L = 10;(*parameters*)
 
 (*Definig Collocation points*)
 y = -Cos[N[Pi/n] Range[0., n]];
 {T, Tprime} = recurrenceTables[y, n];
 Tprime = 2 Tprime/L;
 (*Defining all the functions we need*)
 Z[x_] := L (x + 1)/2;
 v[Z_] := Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z];
 a[Z_] := Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z];
 h[Z_] := 
  Exp[-(F/4.0 ita) Z] Sqrt[((4.0 B)/
       F) + (1 - ((4.0 B)/F)) Exp[(F/4.0 ita) Z]];
 
 Zy = Map[Z, y];
 Vbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v, Zy]]];
 Vbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[v', Zy]]];
 
 Abar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a, Zy]]];
 Abarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[a', Zy]]];
 
 Hbar = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h, Zy]]];
 Hbarprime = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Map[h', Zy]]];
 
 (*creating entries of the final U and W matrix below, \
solution={a1,h1,v1}*)
 eq1 = \[Lambda] a1[z] + a[z] v1'[z] + a'[z] v1[z] + v[z] a1'[z] + 
   v'[z] a1[z];
 eq2 = \[Lambda] a[z] h1[z] - a[z] h[z] v1'[z] - a[z] v'[z] h1[z] - 
   h[z] v'[z] a1[z] + v[z] h[z] a1'[z] + v[z] a'[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z] a'[z] v1[z] + (F/(2.0*ita)) h1[z];
 eq3 = \[Lambda] (h[z]^2 a1[z] - 2.0 a[z] h[z] h1[z]) - 
   2.0 a[z] v[z] h[z] h1'[z] - 2.0 a[z] v[z] h'[z] h1[z] - 
   2.0 a[z] h[z] h'[z] v1[z] - 2.0 v[z] h[z] h'[z] a1[z] + 
   v[z] h[z]^2 a1'[z] + 2.0 v[z] a'[z] h[z] h1[z] + 
   h[z]^2 a'[z] v1[z] - ((2.0*B)/ita) a[z] a1[z];
 
 T2 = Abar . T; T31 = Hbar . Hbar . T;
 T32 = -2.0 Abar . Hbar . T; 
 U = -ArrayFlatten[{{T, 0. T, 0. T}, {0. T, T2, 0. T}, {T31, T32, 
      0. T}}];
 
 
 
 A1 = Vbar . Tprime + Vbarprime . T; H1 = 0. T;
 V1 = Abar . Tprime + Abarprime . T;
 V2 = Hbar . Abarprime . T - Abar . Hbar . Tprime;
 A2 = Vbar . Hbar . Tprime - Hbar . Vbarprime . T;
 H2 = Vbar . Abarprime . T - Abar . Vbarprime . T + (F/(2.0*ita)) T;
 H3 = -2. Abar . Vbar . Hbar . Tprime - 
   2. Abar . Vbar . Hbarprime . T + 2. Vbar . Abarprime . Hbar . T;
 V3 = Hbar . Hbar . Abarprime . T - 2.0 Abar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T;
 A3 = Vbar . Hbar . Hbar . Tprime - 
   2.0 Vbar . Hbar . Hbarprime . T - (2.0 B/ita) Abar . T; 
 W = ArrayFlatten[{{A1, H1, V1}, {A2, H2, V2}, {A3, H3, V3}}];
 
 (*final generalized eigenvalue problem \[Lambda]UX=WX*){vals, funs} =
   Eigensystem[{W, U}]; vals = DeleteCases[vals, ComplexInfinity];
 list[i] = Take[SortBy[vals, Abs[Re[#]] &], i];, {i, 100, 400, 50}]


ComplexListPlot[Table[list[i], {i, 100, 400, 50}], AspectRatio -> 1/2,
  PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 100, 400, 50}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

There are several clusters with $Re(\lambda)>0$, and $Re(\lambda)<0$. The largest cluster is around $Re(\lambda)=0$. Please, note, there is large cluster with $Re(\lambda)=-0.8$ as in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289044/how-to-find-eigenvalues/289141#289141).

Comment: Thanks again.I really appreciate your help @Alex Trounev. Is there another way to just look at the numbers rather than clusters?

Comment: @Fun123 There is cluster with $Re(\lambda)=\sqrt{2}$. Maybe you need this one?